# How to create provider pact verification in python

Tags: python-3.x, pact

I am trying to build a pact verification against consumer contract using python. Basically I am reading the consumer pact from the broker and trying to verify it. The provider real API is hosted on GCP.

I am really confused if I need to create a provider mock ( I thought we create it only on consumer side) to run the verification or I have to run it against the production API (hosted on GCP)?

In the case it is a provider mock on localhost, how should I built it?

Actually when it is running locally, I feel like I am going to hard code the actual response as in the `user-app.py`. Hence, when the production API change, I have to reflect that change manually on the `user-app.py`. I feel like I am missing something.

Here is the contract

to run the verification:
`pact-verifier --provider-base-url=http://localhost:5001 --pact-url=tests/recommendations.recommendations-api-recommendations.basket.model.json --provider-states-setup-url=http://localhost:5001/_pact/provider_states`

Comment: Please see: [Why is Can someone help me? not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)  for more details.

Comment: please ask the question like this:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

With Pact you only mock the provider on the *consumer side*, because you're unit testing the consumer code.

When you test the provider, Pact stands in for the consumer, so you absolutely do not mock the provider here (otherwise, what confidence would you get?)

You should:

1. Run the provider locally (ideally not to a deployed environment, the kind of testing we are avoiding and usually helping to replace with contract testing is end-to-end integrated tests)
2. Mock out any third party dependencies to increase reliability/determinism

See also this page on testing scope: https://docs.pact.io/getting_started/testing-scope

You may find these [examples](https://docs.pactflow.io/docs/examples/) helpful.

Comment: thanks @mattew. Actually the provider is hosted in Google cloud platform as an endpoint. If I run the provider app locally, how can I connect to the real provider in this case?

Comment: The answer is to run it locally and test before you deploy to GCP. That is the real provider.

Comment: Not sure if this helps but if you have a staging environment that the app is deployed to, you could use that instead as the provider url. I had to use that as in my case the service is part of a large monolith application which would have been challenging to install locally